# Is there a LaTeX3 equivalent for \@ifpackageloaded?

Tags: latex3

Is there a LaTeX3 equivalent for `\@ifpackageloaded`?

Comment: Won't the LaTeX2 version work?

Comment: It works, but I thought I could have my whole file in the new syntax, at one point. Maybe that is not possible, yet.

Comment: I could answer `\let\ltx_if_pkg_loaded:nTF\@ifpackageloaded` yes, there is now?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, there isn't. But you can easily build it.

```
\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \mhchem_package_if_loaded:n { p, T, F , TF }
 {
  \use:c { @ifpackageloaded } { #1 } { \prg_return_true: } { \prg_return_false: }
 }
```

This will define the conditionals

```
\mhchem_package_if_loaded:nTF
\mhchem_package_if_loaded:nT
\mhchem_package_if_loaded:nF
```

and the predicate form

```
\mhchem_package_if_loaded_p:n
```

to be used in boolean expressions.

A test:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prg_new_conditional:Nnn \mhchem_package_if_loaded:n { p, T, F , TF }
 {
  \use:c { @ifpackageloaded } { #1 } { \prg_return_true: } { \prg_return_false: }
 }

% now let's test it

\mhchem_package_if_loaded:nTF { expl3 }
 { \typeout{Yes~expl3} }
 { \typeout{No~expl3} }

\mhchem_package_if_loaded:nT { expl3 }
 { \typeout{Yes~expl3} }

\mhchem_package_if_loaded:nTF { kantlipsum }
 { \typeout{Yes~kantlipsum} }
 { \typeout{No~kantlipsum} }

\mhchem_package_if_loaded:nF { kantlipsum }
 { \typeout{No~kantlipsum} }

\bool_if:nTF
 {
  \mhchem_package_if_loaded_p:n {expl3}
  ||
  \mhchem_package_if_loaded_p:n {kantlipsum}
 }
 { \typeout{Yes~expl3~or~kantlipsum} }
 { \typeout{No~expl3~or~kantlipsum} }

\bool_if:nTF
 {
  \mhchem_package_if_loaded_p:n {expl3}
  &&
  \mhchem_package_if_loaded_p:n {kantlipsum}
 }
 { \typeout{Yes~expl3~and~kantlipsum} }
 { \typeout{No~expl3~and~kantlipsum} }

\stop
```

The relevant console output:

```
Yes expl3
Yes expl3
No kantlipsum
No kantlipsum
Yes expl3 or kantlipsum
No expl3 and kantlipsum
```

Comment: Can you update your answer? that command is implemented since (LaTeX release 2021-11-15) `ltnews43`...saludos

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL Not sure what you mean. What command is implemented?

Comment: `\IfPackageLoadedTF {⟨package⟩} {⟨true⟩}{⟨false⟩}`

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL That's not `expl3`. For instance it lacks the predicate version.